# JCaptcha and the SpringFramework

Tags: java, spring, ubuntu, tomcat7, jcaptcha

I have created REST API for captcha - using JCaptcha in spring framework.

Everything works fine when i place the war file inside tomcat7 server present in windows OS environment.

For deployment, when i use same war file in tomcat7 web server  which present in Ubuntu 14.04 the api suddenly start giving http 500 response code with following exception :

```
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Handler processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class sun.awt.image.codec.JPEGImageEncoderImpl
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:820)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:716)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:647)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:552)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:620)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
com.televital.vitalware.services.CORSFilter.doFilterInternal(CORSFilter.java:29)
org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
```

I have reffered following link for the development of the API

https://jcaptcha.atlassian.net/wiki/display/general/JCaptcha+and+the+SpringFramework

Please help me.It alredy took my 2 days.

Answer (score 0):

There are two possibilities.

- `sun.awt.image.codec.*` is included in `<JDK installation
  folder>\jre\lib\rt.jar`. So check this jar is already existed in your
  Linux machine or not.
- The second one is you need to turn on [Headless mode](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/headless-136834.html) in your Linux machine.Before you run tomcat startup script, you need to turn on Headless mode like this

  ```
   JAVA_OPTS='-Djava.awt.headless=true'
  ```

Comment: Thank you for immediate replay.

Comment: finally got the solution its actually because of open-jdk.I removed it and installed oracle-java8-installer and its actually worked like any thing.

Answer (score 0):

From the stack trace its evident that on Ubuntu the application is not able to locate the `sun.awt.image.codec.JPEGImageEncoderImpl` class from `<JDK installation>\jre\lib\rt.jar`.

To resolve the error check below

- JDK is installed correctly (*if not re-install*)
- `JAVA_HOME` is configured correctly
- If above two are correct then use [headless](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/headless-136834.html) mode by specifying  `-Djava.awt.headless=true`

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions.

Comment: finally got the solution its actually because of open-jdk.I removed it and installed oracle-java8-installer and its actuly worked like charm.